# multiple checkboxes again in python

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, python-3.10

I am a noob, I am trying to create many checkboxes at once. ultimately, my program would create folders in the same directory, depending on which ones have been checked.
I simply do not get the IntVar() use.
I would love for some of the boxes to be ticked by default...according to the entries in my dictionary
I even tried to put the "variable" = 1 in my loop and the boxes are not ticked!!!

```
import os
from tkinter import *


def create_folders():
    for item in list_of_folders:
        print(item)
            # os.mkdir(list_of_folders[item])


list_of_folders = {"Audio":0,"AVI":0, "Footage":1, "GFX":1, "MP4":1, "MOV":1, "MPG":0,  "Photography":1, "Press":1}
num_row=0
window = Tk()
var=[]
window.title("Folder Creation v1.0")
window.minsize(300, 200)
window.config(padx=100, pady=100)

for item in list_of_folders:
    num_row +=1
    Checkbutton(window, text=item, variable=list_of_folders[item]).grid(row=num_row, sticky=W)



Label(window, text="").grid(column=0, row=10, sticky=W)

Button(window, text="Create Folders", command=create_folders).grid(column=0, row=15, sticky=W)

Button(window, text="Exit", command=window.destroy).grid(column=1, row=15, sticky=W)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was so damn close to the victory there is nothing fancy that I added, I just optimized your code a bit and used the `IntVar(value=1)` to check the button and stored the variable of that `IntVar()` into a list to later iterate on final button click to actually create the directories.

Calling the get method on the `IntVar()` returns the current state of the checkbox as you can see in the screenshot.

```
import os
from tkinter import *


def create_folders():
    for button in boxes:
        if button["state"].get(): #check if its checked or not
            print("Creating folder", button["text"])
            os.mkdir(button["text"])


boxes = []

list_of_folders = {
    "Audio": 0,
    "AVI": 0, 
    "Footage": 1, 
    "GFX": 1, 
    "MP4": 0, 
    "MOV": 1,
    "MPG": 0,  
    "Photography": 1,
    "Press": 1
}

num_row=0
window = Tk()
window.title("Folder Creation v1.0")
window.minsize(300, 200)
window.config(padx=100, pady=100)

for item in list_of_folders.keys():
    lookup = IntVar(value=list_of_folders[item])
    Checkbutton(window, text = item, variable=lookup).grid(row=len(boxes) + 1, sticky=W)
    boxes.append({ 
        "text": item, #store name to create the directory
        "state": lookup #store reference to check whether we need to create directory
    })



Label(window, text="").grid(column=0, row=10, sticky=W)

Button(window, text="Create Folders", command=create_folders).grid(column=0, row=15, sticky=W)

Button(window, text="Exit", command=window.destroy).grid(column=1, row=15, sticky=W)
window.mainloop()
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Very Much Zain! This community is AWESOME! I've tried to upvote but I cannot yet! Thanks again!